# ssh forward multiple ports

Tags: ssh

So this works for me:

```
ssh -v -L 8080:remotewebserver:8080 me@jumphost
```

How about if I would also like to include more ports?

I want to forward not only 8080, but also 8443, 8923 and 8181?

Do I need to do a new connection for each port?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you do not need one [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) connection per forwarded port, just add further `-L` statements:

`ssh -L LPort1:RHOST1:RPORT1 -L LPORT2:RHOST2:RPORT2 me@ju.mp.ho.st`

This can be shortened to `ssh jump`, using the "alias" `jump`, if you set up a matching section in your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host jump
    User myUserName
    Hostname ju.mp.ho.st
    Port 2345
    LocalForward 8080 remotewebserver:8080
    LocalForward 8443 remotewebserver:8443
    LocalForward 8923 remotewebserver:8923
    LocalForward 8181 remotewebserver:8181

# Eliminates reconnection delay, and does not try to re-forward ports:
Host *
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
```

I have used this technique for many years, surely already with 10+ ports, but when I need more ports forwarded, I use Dynamic Socks Proxy support `-D`.

Comment: When connecting, I would see these error messages for each forwarded port: `bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port:` then `Could not request local forwarding.` With the Control* settings, these are gone, thanks! PS: I've been using that comment flag a lot on SE, and you're the first other person I've seen also using it. Appreciate that :)